# How do I run a Flask App on a remote server with git hooks post-receive?

Tags: python, git, flask

I added a post-receive git hook on the server side so that a flask app runs after the receive. The script works and the app runs on the server. However, from the client side, when pushing, the process gets stuck at even when the flask app is already running on the server.

```
Pushing to root@192.168.XX.XX:~/api/
```

Here is the post-receive script.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Post-receive hook to make the API
# run back up again after the changes are made.
python3 ../../api_run.py &

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve this problem.

Instead of the previous command, I added some few more to silence the terminal output.

```
python3 ../../api_run.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```